# How to make .NET Core Dependency Injection and Models/DTOs type-aware for Generics

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-core, dependency-injection

If you add a service that can work with several models using .NET Core's Dependency Injection, how do you prevent getting an error from the DI service registration not having any knowledge of your models?

For example:

```
    private static void ConfigureServices(ServiceCollection services)
    {
        // is used by the three registered services below
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IDataFileReader<>),
            typeof(DataFileReader<>));
        // but when these services get new'd up each needs to 'inform' 
        // the generic from above the model to work with
        services.AddScoped<BankruptcyCalculator>();
        // for example the above Calculator needs to be able to work with
        // a Bankruptcy model and List<Bankruptcy>
        services.AddScoped<LossMitigationCalculator>();
        // LossMitigation model and List<LossMitgation>
        services.AddScoped<PaymentCalculator>();
        // Payment model and List<Payment>
    }
```

I'm sure there is a second piece to this puzzle that I am missing. I'm new DI and DI in a .NET Core console project. You are not forced to always go down a Repository-style pattern that hides the generic in an interface behind a non-generic class, right? That is what I was kinda doing with `IDataFileReader` / `DataFileReader`. I have 20 models in total on this part of the project... don't really want to do 20 repo-style classes if I don't have to.

note: the models are tied to how I deserialize some CSV files, and are used as read-only from those files.

Comment: `for example the above Calculator needs to be able to work with a Bankruptcy model and List<Bankruptcy>` show us that code

Comment: And 11 more models... 2 more listing for example.

Comment: Can you share how `BankruptcyCalculator` is dependent on `IDataFileReader<>`?

Comment: I don't understand the problem you are trying to solve. Are you doing something else than injecting an IDataFileReader<Bankruptcy> into the BankruptcyCalculator? If so; please show the code. If not, why doesn't injecting `IDataFileReader<Bankruptcy>` into the `BankruptcyCalculator` work for you? You might want to update your question with this information.

Comment: Steven, so I guess you are saying in my Registration of the IoC I need to specify each and every injection... so 20 times. IDataFileReader<Bankruptcy> and 19 more. If I branch out and use one of the more advanced IoC containers... can I use naming conventions or so other pattern to get around all this upfront config? What IoC Frameworks have the most mind-share? It has been 10 years since I last looked.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I cannot because of NDA/Contracts I signed. But in short ... it is a model for each record coming out of the CSV file. The model is decorated with the Index attribute from the CsvHelper framework. So it re-hydrates to List<model> from a CSV and lets me act on it.

Comment: Not real application code, can you share a sample code to which can demonstrate what you are trying to do,? Also are you saying that BankruptcyCalculator class is dependent on `IDataFileReader<Bankruptcy>` interface but you don't have that exact interface but you have `IDataFileReader<T>` interface and class `DataFileReader<T>`?

Comment: I was probably not using the right lingo but I think this kind of pattern gets me further down the road to where I am headed - https://chaitanyasuvarna.wordpress.com/2021/03/21/factory-pattern-di-in-net-core/ Even though it feels like a backdoor to Service Locator... I should be able to do anything I like from there.